# How to fetch recent score of all users

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

How to get all recent scores of all users?

| id | user_id | score | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 220 | 2022-03-03 00:00:01 | 2022-03-03 00:00:01 |
| 2 | 1 | 230 | 2022-03-04 00:00:01 | 2022-03-04 00:00:01 |
| 3 | 2 | 210 | 2022-03-05 00:00:01 | 2022-03-05 00:00:01 |
| 4 | 2 | 200 | 2022-03-06 00:00:01 | 2022-03-06 00:00:01 |
| 5 | 3 | 220 | 2022-03-07 00:00:01 | 2022-03-07 00:00:01 |
| 6 | 3 | 220 | 2022-03-08 00:00:01 | 2022-03-08 00:00:01 |
| 7 | 2 | 180 | 2022-03-09 00:00:01 | 2022-03-09 00:00:01 |
| 8 | 1 | 220 | 2022-03-10 00:00:01 | 2022-03-10 00:00:01 |
| 9 | 3 | 120 | 2022-03-11 00:00:01 | 2022-03-11 00:00:01 |

`select distinct user_id, score from user_score order by created_at desc`

this query is throwing me error. How else this data can be queried?

Comment: Since your title clearly states *Postgres* I removed the *MySql* tag; try using the correct `order by` syntax.

Comment: @Stu ```order by``` syntax is a typo, which I've corrected but I don't think that's the right usage

Comment: What does *throwing me error* mean? I don't see any error message quoted in your post.  When you get an error you want us to help you with, you MUST include the **complete, exact error message** in your question. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from where we are, so you need to put it in your post. You're asking us for free help, and it's in your own best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by providing the details.

Comment: Add `created_at` to select list e.g. `select distinct user_id, score, created_by ...` as the error message no doubt told you: *ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   distinct on (user_id) *
from     t 
order by user_id, created_at desc
```

| id | user_id | score | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 | 220 | 2022-03-10 00:00:01 | 2022-03-10 00:00:01 |
| 7 | 2 | 180 | 2022-03-09 00:00:01 | 2022-03-09 00:00:01 |
| 9 | 3 | 120 | 2022-03-11 00:00:01 | 2022-03-11 00:00:01 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HITWyL2n)

Comment: Surprisingly snowflake doesn't support `distinct on` :LOL